# Is it possible to send one message to multiple receiving sockets in constant time?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

This is more on the general side, but I have lately had the need to send a lot of messages received via a WebSocket API to multiple child processes via UNIX domain sockets in python. Pure threads are no alternative since I need true concurrency (Hope I am not confusing it with parallelism) and so only processes remain. Sharing memory between main and child-processes introduces a bigger overhead than having all of them just listen on their own socket.

The procedure looks as follows:

1. Thread in the main process listens to incoming WebSocket message and puts them into a queue
2. Main process busy-spins and checks for new messages in the queue, if there is one, it sends it to multiple (probably around 3-4) child processes.

After profiling the above script, I found out that it takes around 3msec per child process to send a message. Considering the need for a high throughput, I would rather have to wait 3msec per message than 9msec in the case of 3 child processes. Would there be any possibility to cut this time from O(n) to O(1)?

So far only async has come to mind, but I would like to not use it if possible.

Comment: basically you want publish subscibe model. have u tried any message queue? kafka for example..

Comment: 3ms is a lot, even for Python. How exactly are you sending the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a fixed set of child processes, i.e a set has 3/n processes and you pick a set and forward to all, then, you may consider using one multicast IP/sockets per child process set.

Or if child processing overhead is not of much concern you can make all child process listen on the same multicast group, meaning all child processes gets all messages from the main process and check message parameter to decide if the message is intended for it or not.

Multicast IP does Layer 2 level broadcast so the packet is sent only once on the wire and all the sockets in the multicast group read the same message at the same time.